# Creating a Custom Binding in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I've been trying to create a custom binding to output this type of header XML:

```
<soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
     <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-BEC9D84D8B68A3118D14543420311491">
        <wsse:Username>user</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">pass</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">hBcjVXk/NxiSiva5xXKphA==</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>2016-02-01T15:53:51.146Z</wsu:Created>
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
```

Here is my code so far:

```
        var customBinding= new CustomBinding();

        var securityBindingElement = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
        securityBindingElement.IncludeTimestamp = false;
        customBinding.Elements.Add(securityBindingElement);
        customBinding.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement());

        var transportElement = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();

        customBinding.Elements.Add(transportElement);
```

However I keep receiving a message stating:

`The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings`.

I'm pretty certain it has to do with my custombinding but i'm having a terribly difficult time trying to figure out what properties need set to what. Appreciate any guidance!!!

Comment: Your binding looks much like my custom binding which is working - although I used a BinaryMessageEncoding.. which would be worth a try

Comment: Thanks - new error message: `The content type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+msbin1). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly`

Comment: you know when you load the reference in vs, you're asked how you want to handle various collections - Im wondering if this is what this is doing for you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135392/webservice-returns-wrong-content-type-response-header talks of this error

Comment: Well the thing is - when I use a wshttp binding it creates almost the XML i need, with the exception of like 4 or 5 extra nodes in the header section. after my research I was told to create a custom binding, but the disconnect for me is how to create a custom binding that mimics the wshttp binding with exception of the nodes that i do not want to show

Comment: Sometimes wizards themselves becomes amazed with their own magic. (This is about XAML technology in general) :-)

Comment: `securityBindingElement.IncludeTimestamp = false` might not be what you need, hm?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the client time and the server time are mismatching, at least the error seems like it...

Could you check your timers?

If i'm right see this: [How to: Set a Max Clock Skew](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738468.aspx)